# checking if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if a checkbox is checked via jQuery?

Can I just add an ID or class to the element and do this?

```
if($('#element').val() == 1) { 
  //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if($('#element').is(':checked')){

    //checkbox is checked

}
```

or

```
if($('#element:checked').length > 0){

    //checkbox is checked

}
```

or in jQuery 1.6+:

```
if($('#element:checked').prop('checked') === true){

    //checkbox is checked

}
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where you are trying to do this. Generally you can do:

```
$('#element').is(':checked');
```

or

```
$('#element')[0].checked;
```

or

```
 $('#element').prop('checked');
```

or older version of jquery ( < 1.6) that doesn't support prop, attr used to do the job of prop as well to set/reset properties of element (Incase of standalone attributes like checked, selected, disabled etc...);

```
 $('#element').attr('checked') //will return boolean value
```

If it is in the context of the checkbox like, if in a `change` event you can just do:

```
  this.checked
```

Comment: @user2864740 Not really see the comment and the statement before that. For your proof test it against older version of jquery <=1.5 or so

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry, really sleepy. `:P` Either way, yeah, in jQuery < 1.6, there was no `.prop()` so `.attr()` did retrieve DOM properties back then.

Comment: Also older version of jq that doesn't support prop used to make up for setting property for standalone attributes.

Comment: @user2864740 Here you go one with version 1.5 http://jsfiddle.net/tgY2Y/

Answer (score 0):

Using element's id or class is a good way of doing all this, but since we're using jQuery, you might use their API and here is the solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') {
  // do the stuff here..
}
```

You can also use `#element` instead of the `input[type="checkbox"]'`.

This way, you can get to know that the checkbox is checked.